# Scanner Canon Maxify MB5160 not recognised on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: scanner, canon

Unable to connect to scanner Canon MB5160

This is my first question on Ask Ubuntu, so please bear with me.

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, 
Canon Maxify MB 5160

I'm a Linux newbie, recently converted from Windows. All my apps are working fine, except the scanner software. The above multifunction printer prints fine, but Simple Scanner and gScan2pdf don't recognise it, so I can't scan.

What I've done:
- installed Canon driver scangearmp2-3.40-1-deb
- installed Canon driver cnijfilter2-5.40-1-deb
Command: sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/scangearmp2_3.40-1_amd64.deb successful. "installation has been completed."
- run lsusb: no Canon printers show up.

- register the printer. Result: successful.
- set as default printer.
- run lsusb: no printers
- reboot, run update, run lsusb: no printers
- check device list in Settings/Devices/Printers: Canon printer is correctly listed and installed.
- check scanning software: no scanner installed / recognised (though the printer prints).
- uninstall scanning software and reinstalled: no solution.

Is anyone in the Ubuntu community able to help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the scanner networked or connected via usb? Does the Canon scangear app work? I got a similar device working.

Comment: The scanner's on a wireless network, but I found the only way to register it was by using the USB cable. I can't see the scangear app - even though I've run the dpkg -iG command, as mentioned. I expected to see the app in the 'show applications' window, but it's not there.

Comment: If you successfully installed the Canon scangear app, you can start it by typing the command `scangearmp2`. The first thing this app does is pop up a box that looks lets you look for scanners on the network. If the Canon scangear app doesn't find the scanner, there are big problems. But the first step is finding this app and seeing if it works. Our printer/scanner is an MB2320 and I've gotten it to work with simplescan and xsane as well as scangearmp2. But only scangearmp2 can use the document feeder.

Comment: Hi Organic Marble. Thx for response. Much appreciated. I'm happy to say your instructions to use scangearmp2 from the terminal worked. The app found the scanner and updated the scanner list. I was then able to scan using the popup window that scangearmp2 displayed. However, the gscan2pdf and simplescan apps still fail to see the scanner. On the terminal window, I noticed the error message: "(scangearmp2:17349): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:46:15.783: Attempting to set the permissions of `/home/username/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Operation not permitted"
How do I resolve that? Thx.

Comment: Good news! I am out of town for a few days but will get back to thus when I return.